# Spark broadcasts right dataset from left join, which causes org.apache.spark.sql.execution.OutOfMemorySparkException

Tags: apache-spark, scala-spark

Spark broadcasts right dataset from left join, which causes `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.OutOfMemorySparkException: Size of broadcasted table far exceeds estimates and exceeds limit of spark.driver.maxResultSize`, despite I used settings to disable it - `spark.sql.adaptive.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1, spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=false, spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1`.  I found that in some conditions Spark can use broadcast nested loop join anyway, as the only option for join, especially if it is non-equi join https://stackoverflow.com/a/76390114/20321407.
I added "MERGEJOIN" hint and enabled debug logging. In the log I found following

```
DEBUG ExtractEquiJoinKeys: Considering join on: Some((((_1#119114._1.card_number = _2#119115.card) OR (_1#119114._1.card_number = _2#119115.visible_number_on_card)) OR (_1#119114._2.string = _2#119115.visible_number_on_card)))
WARN HintErrorLogger: Hint (strategy=merge) is not supported in the query: no equi-join keys.
```

The question is: are there any options to avoid broadcast join with `OR` conditions? Or it is only option to use several joins one by one? Is it join with `OR` condition might be equi join and not broadcasted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the only option to avoid broadcasting is split join conditions to several consecutive joins.